# Создание таймера через структурную директиву Angular для вывода в разметку

Tags: angular

```
    **
```

> ```
> Здравствуйте, очень нужна Ваша помощь, на данный момент учусь на
>   курсах Angular, и на всех ресурсах одно и тоже. На уроке на поставили
>   задачу реализовать таймер через структурную директиву который должен
>   выводиться в разметку.Я написала код, но он почему то не работает.
>   Наверное криво написала. Может кто нибудь помочь разобраться?Заранее
>   благодарна)
> ```

`` Код в разметке: <p*appCountdown="endDate">{{display}} </p>
Код в директиве:
    import { Directive, Input, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

        @Directive({
          selector: '[appCountdown]'
        })
        export class CountdownDirective {
      private display;
      constructor(
        private template: TemplateRef<any>,
        private container: ViewContainerRef
      ) {}
      @Input() set appCountdown(endDate: any) {

        const resMillecekund = endDate - Date.now();
        const resDay = Math.floor(resMillecekund / (8.64e+7));

        if (resDay >= 1) {
          this.display = `${resDay}<span>days left</span>`;
          this.container.createEmbeddedView(this.template);
          return;
        } else if (resDay < 1 && resDay > 0) {

          const resSecund =  Math.floor(resMillecekund / 1000);
          const resMinutes =  Math.floor(resSecund / 60);
          const resHour = Math.floor(resMinutes / 60);

          const reminder_seconds = resSecund % 60;
          const reminder_minutes = resMinutes % 60;
          const reminder_hour = resHour % 24;

          this.display = `${reminder_seconds}:${reminder_minutes}:${reminder_hour}`;

          setTimeout(() => {
            this.container.createEmbeddedView(this.template );
          }, 1000);
          return;
        }
      }
    }</pre> ``

Comment: отформатируйте пожалуйста код, это раз, второе - что именно не работает? у вас какая-то "задница" с датами, почему нельзя просто миллисекунды передавать?

Comment: Первый раз на этом сайте, поэтому нет опыта работы с кодом. А проблема в том, что не отображается вообще элемент с директивой при просмотре таймера через сервер

Comment: какой сервер? оО

Comment: Даты я изменю, это не принципиально, я не думаю что основная проблема в этом

Comment: Я имела в виду через браузер

Comment: смотрите, у вас просто условие неправильное

Comment: в первом случае `res >= 1`, а во втором `resDay < 1 && resDay > 0`

Comment: `resDay < 1 && resDay > 0` - вот эта часть меня беспокоит - меньше чем 1 и больше чем 0? ))

Comment: действительно) сейчас буду исправлять

Comment: нет наверное так правильно, условие состоит в том, что если суток осталось больше чем 1 то выводить колличество суток, а если меньше чем 1 сутки, то выводить часы:минуты:секунды

Comment: я подставил туда разные числа и получил отрицательное число, условие не срабатывает, `resDay < 1 && resDay > 0` - это условие неправильное, сделайте просто `else`, а не `else if`

Comment: ок, спасибо буду пробовать.  А в остальном вы не видите никаких критически важных ошибок?

Comment: ну, смотрите, сеттер вам не нужен в данном случае, я бы просто создал байндинг и в `ngOnInit` выполнял некую проверку, далее создал бы 2 разных метода для двух условий и вызывал бы их в `ngOnInit`, ретурны внутри условий вам не нужны

Comment: А разве в Директиве доступно ngOninit?

Comment: почему вы думаете что нет?)

Comment: Потому что пробовала добавить, можно что не заимплементила((

Comment: интерфейсы это сахар и имплементить их необязательно чтоб метод заработал

Comment: Спасибо большое, у нас конечно очень хороший преподаватель, но как -то эту тему немного поверхностно рассказал

Comment: если у вас так и не получится решить проблему, то напишите какой результат вы хотите получить, я добавлю ответ с кодом